# returning index of the biggest value

Tags: c++

This is the program that I need to solve:

> Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of pancakes eaten for breakfast by 10 different people (`Person 1, Person 2, ..., Person 10`).
>   Once the data has been entered the program must analyze the data and output which person ate the most pancakes for breakfast.

Could anybody write the code for returning the index of biggest value (I have labeled it as "h")

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int x[11];
    int y;
    int h;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> i[x];
        cout << "Person: " << i << " has eaten " << i[x] << " pancakes" << endl
        y = x[0];
        h = x[0];


        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            if (x[j] > y)
            {
                y = x[j];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "The most pancakes are eaten by Person " << h << " with " << y << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _'Could anybody write the code for returning the index of biggest value'_ Certainly no! That's **your** homework!!

Comment: What's so difficult about this problem? You should be able to find resources all over the Internet.

Comment: How about first relabelling your variables with something more descriptive than x,y, and h? May make it a bit easier to work through your logic tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, should work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int x[11];
    int ans, ansmax = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> x[i]; // You had wrong variable here
        cout << "Person: " << i << " has eaten " << x[i] << " pancakes" << endl
        if(x[i] > ansmax)
        {
            ansmax = x[i];
            ans = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "The most pancakes are eaten by Person " << ans << " with " << ansmax << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My five cents

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int person[N];

    // Entering initial data
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        cout << "Enter number of pancakes eaten by person " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> person[i];
    }

    //  Finding the index (favorite) of the person who has eaten the most pancakes.
    int favorite = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( person[favorite] < person[i] ) favorite = i;
    }

    // Now all is ready to show the result
    cout << "\nThe most pancakes are eaten by Person " << favorite + 1 
         << " with " << person[favorite] << endl;

    system( "pause" );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>

int index = std::max_element(x, x + 11) - x;
```